# Running Julia on MacOS X: Missing libc++.1.dy

Tags: macos

When trying to run Julia 0.3.2 in MacOS X I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Julia-0.3.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia
  Reason: image not found
```

When I run Julia 0.2.1 it works:

```
Hermione:~ emd$ exec '/Users/emd/Desktop/Julia-0.2.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" to list help topics
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.2.1 (2014-02-11 06:30 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0

julia>
```

Looking at the `julia` binary for 0.3.2 I get this:

```
Hermione:bin emd$ otool -L julia
julia:
    @rpath/libjulia.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

But the `julia` binary for 0.2.1 gives this:

```
Hermione:bin emd$ otool -L julia
julia:
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    @rpath/libjulia.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 744.19.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 57.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by reading the web site more closely.

The problem is that `/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib` is not present on the MacOS X 10.6.8 system - but why? MacOS X 10.6.8 uses `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib`.

So I thought - maybe it's on newer versions of MacOS X?

The [download page](http://julialang.org/downloads/) for Julia has this tidbit:

> On Mac, a Julia-version.dmg file is provided, which contains
>   Julia.app. Installation is the same as any other Mac software – copy
>   the Julia.app to your hard-drive (anywhere) or run from the disk
>   image. Julia supports all OS X 10.7 and later. If you use Snow Leopard
>   (OSX 10.6), Julia 0.2.1 was the last release of Julia that supported
>   it.

So the difference in libraries points to the minimum requirements for Julia: *Julia 0.3.2 isn't supported on MacOS X 10.6.*